# JPA/MySql issue

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa

I am building JPA based application using mysql and ecliselink.I have very strange issue when try to insert stuff into my database.I am able to insert data into single table but when it comes to one-to-may and vice versa something goes wrong.Currently I have 2 main and 1 reference table(it holds the foreign keys of the other two tables).It is strange because I dont have "sequence" in my database table When I try to insert data into any of my tables I get this exception:

```
[EL Info]: 2012-03-15 17:52:28.64--ServerSession(18621340)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461 
[EL Info]: 2012-03-15 17:52:29.23--ServerSession(18621340)--file:/D:/git-eclipse/Martin/reference/build/classes/_reference login successful 
[EL Warning]: 2012-03-15 17:52:29.389--ClientSession(31843177)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException 
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'eclipse1.sequence' doesn't exist 
Error Code: 1146 
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ? 
bind => [2 parameters bound] 
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?") 

Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'eclipse1.sequence' doesn't exist 
Error Code: 1146 
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ? 
bind => [2 parameters bound] 
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?") 
[EL Info]: 2012-03-15 17:52:29.394--ServerSession(18621340)--file:/D:/git-eclipse/Martin/reference/build/classes/_reference logout successful 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManager. 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.verifyOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:1665) 
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:1529) 
at OneToManyRelation.main(OneToManyRelation.java:47)
```

I am posting one class only because others are quite similar

```
@Entity

    @Table(name="category")

    public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CategoryID")
    private int CategoryID;

/**
* @return the id
*/
public int getId() {
return CategoryID;
}

/**
* @param id the id to set
*/
public void setId(int CategoryID) {
this.CategoryID = CategoryID;
}

@Column(name="category", nullable=false, length=50, insertable=true)
private String category;

/**
* @return the category
*/
public String getCategory() {
return category;
}


public void setCategory(String category) {
this.category = category;
}

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "templateemail", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name="categoryId", unique = true) 
},
inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name="templateId")
}
)
private Set<Template> template;

/**
* 
*/
public Set<Template> getChildren() {
return template;
}

/**
* 
*/
public void setChildren(Set<Template> template) {
this.template = template;
}

}
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Martin I am affraid what you have posted is not your code. So, how could we tell what is wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry guys I`m quite new here,I will do my best to improve my improve my questions

Answer (score 2):

Seeing the code would help finding what's wrong with it. But by judging on the error message only, it seems you chose to use a sequence or table generator, and that this generator relies (by default) on a table named `sequence`, that doesn't exist in the database.

Create this table, or configure the generator to use an existing table, or change the ID generator.

Comment: My answer is the same. create the required table, or configure a generator that does what you want. You seem to hope that JPA will generate IDs for you without any sequence, table, or autoincrement field in the database. Choose the strategy you want, and create the necessary tables and/or columns in database to support this strategy.

Comment: @JBNizet is right. EclipseLink docs say: "Specifying a strategy of AUTO allows EclipseLink to select the strategy to use. Typically, EclipseLink picks TABLE as the strategy, since it is the most portable strategy. However, when AUTO is specified, schema generation must be used at least once in order for the default table to be created in the database." (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey)